# Firestore UI RecyclerAdapter pass data to second Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore UI Recycler Adapter using Kotlin on android and I would like to select items from it and pass the selected results to a second Recyclerview in a second activity. FirestoreRecyclerOptions has a method setSnapshotArray that may help me if I could pass it in an intent. I also could extend Activity class and make FirestoreRecyclerOptions a global scope var. I could also make use of tag on the viewholder to set a selected flag on my model class. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial on how to can create a [Chat App using Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb) where I have explained how you can pass objects between activities.

Comment: I have no problem passing objects in an intent to a second activity or using shared preferences to essentially do the same thing. Using the setSetSnapshotArray on FirestoreRecyclerOptions is my problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to crud the Firebase recyclerview adapter by using the snapshots object I can move things around access the data collection and DocumentRefrence. I had success with drag and drop as well as inserting/deleting data from the adapter and database using this snapshots object. Having this ability I can now pass data in an intent to second activity Example from the adapter

```
 override fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
    var from: Cust = snapshots.get(fromPosition)
    var toSnap: DocumentSnapshot = snapshots.getSnapshot(toPosition)
    var toRef: DocumentReference = toSnap.reference
    from.positionMo = toPosition

    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
}


fun saveIndexes(){
    for(x in snapshots){
        x.positionMo=snapshots.indexOf(x)
         snapshots.getSnapshot(x.positionMo).reference.update("positionMo",x.positionMo)

    }

}
```